# https clientside and http back end cookie is not sent

Tags: authentication, cookies, https

I am new to web development. At first, I created an authentication system with http protocol for both client dev-server and backend dev-server, which worked properly. However, I had to make the client dev-server secure to implement HLS video player. Therefore, now client side url is (**https**://localhost:15173/login), and backend url (**http**://localhost:3000). When client side url is (**http**://localhost:15173/login), cookie was generated on server-side and sent to the client side. So, I would like to know why this is happening.

Serverside: nodejs, express.js
Client side: javascript, vue3.js

Do I have to make both client side and backend https?

Here is backend code to generate cookie:

```
res.cookie('JWTcookie', accessToken, { httpOnly: true})
                    res.status(200).json(responseJson)
```

Here is backend code to validate cookie:

```
app.get("/login", function (req, res) {
    var JWTcookie = req.cookies.JWTcookie;
    console.log("JWT cookie is here", req.cookies.JWTcookie);
    try {
        console.log("veryfy token is here", verifyToken(JWTcookie));
        const decoded = jwt.verify(JWTcookie, SECRET_KEY, function (err, decoded) {
            return decoded;
        })
        const responseJson = {
            success: true,
            username: decoded.name,
            userID: decoded.id
        }
        res.status(200).json(responseJson);
        // console.log("decoded token ", decoded);
    }
    catch (err) {
        const status = 401
        const message = 'Unauthorized'
        res.send("Not authorized. Better login");
        // res.status(status).json({ status, message })
    }
});
```

Here is client side code (vue.js) to send cookie to the sererside:

```
onMounted(() => {
    const API_URL = "http://localhost:3000/";
    const authStore = userAuthStore();

    axios.get(API_URL + "login", { withCredentials: true }).then(res => {
        if (res.data.success == true) {
            const id = res.data.userID;
            const username = res.data.username;
            authStore.auth();
            authStore.setUser(id, username);
            console.log("mounted.")
            router.push("/video");
        }
        else {
            console.log("Response is here: ", res.data)
        }
    })

})
```

I believe the problem is the lack of understanding of how security system work when one of them is https and the other is http.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

I tried to make the cookie secure by adding:

```
res.cookie('JWTcookie', accessToken, { httpOnly: true, secure: true})
```

But this didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

When I gave both server side and client side https, it worked.